# how to remove the stroke or the border from the jvectormap

Tags: jvectormap

I want to make a dotted datagrid for the worldmap. http://prntscr.com/8oo2tw . I have used the legends(image) for every region in whole map. All seems good but when that legend lies between the boundary of the countries the legend seems to be distorted. How can i remove the stroke (boudaries between the countries) so that dotted image lying between the boundary of the countries doesnot seem distorted.

I have tried making stoke:none and stroke-width:0 and stroke-opacity:0. But doesnot seems working. My code is like:

```
new jvm.Map({
            container: jQuery('#world-map'),
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
            markersSelectable: true,
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            hoverColor: false,
            series: {
                regions: [{
                        scale: {
                            dotted:"<?php echo $base_url .'/'. path_to_theme()?>"+"/images/dot.png",
                            yellowBlue: '../images/icon.png'
                        },
                        attribute: 'fill',
                        values: {
                            "AF": 'dotted',
                            "AX": 'dotted',
                            //all regions with in world_mill_en
                            "ZI": 'dotted',
                            "ZW": 'dotted',
                            "ZM": 'dotted',
                            "_1": 'dotted'                                  
                        },
                        attribute: 'fill',
                    }]
            },                                
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set this parameter in a map object, like this:

```
      regionStyle : {
        initial : {
          fill : "white",
          "fill-opacity" : 1,
          stroke : "black",
          "stroke-width" : 0.0,
          "stroke-opacity" : 1
        },
        hover : {
          "fill-opacity": 1,
          "stroke-width" : 0.0,
        },
        selectedHover : {}
      },
```